# Blog post preview - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How can I add a preview to a blog post to a blog page? For example something like this on the blog page:

Post name
Date
Picture
Preview
Read more

Then on the blog post page:
Post name
Date
Picture
Blog content

At the moment it's displaying all of the blog on the blog page and I want it to just display a brief preview of the block, perhaps the description, and then to display all of the blog in the blog post page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the more tag. Check this page for explanation how: http://en.support.wordpress.com/splitting-content/more-tag/.